# Organizing the list with a pivot

Tags: python

I need to organize a list. The item in the zero index will be the pivot, so that every item in the list smaller will be put left to it in the list, and everything greater will be put right to it in the list.

Now I can't use "sort" or any built-in function in Python. Anyone could give me a clue?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do some sort of quicksort. Is that right? If so, could you include your progress so far if you have any, or what you don't understand?

Comment: Well, actually there's no real progress because I don't know where to begin. I have no experience with Python.

Comment: create two empty list, all elements less than pivot put in list 1 and all elements greater than pivot put them in list 2, than merge list and select pivot as second index in merged list, repeat the steps

Comment: Can't you even use the built-in `len()` function? Or is the list's length given to you separately? There are very many web sites that explain how to do quicksort, which includes your desired partition routine. What research have you done?

Comment: So, start with even the most basic things. Do you know how to create a list in Python? If not, search it and start with that. After that, find out how to index lists, and you'll then be able to get the pivot. If there's any step in particular that's confusing, just share that @Shalom.I

Comment: I believe I can use the len() function, just not aynthing built-in to sort it the way required.

@Aurora0001: I know how to create a list. What do you by "index" lists? As for the pivot, it's needed to be the first item in the list.

Comment: @Shalom.I by indexing a list, I mean given `x = [1, 2, 3]`: `x[0] == 1` and `x[1] == 2` etc.

Comment: Yep, that, too, I know. But still, even though I have an understanding what's needed to be done, I don't know where to begin the translation to "python"... you know...

Answer (score 0):

Since you give no attempted code, I'll just give you an idea of the algorithm.

Go through the list, skipping index 0 where the pivot value is and starting at index 1, and examine the list entries. If the entry is less than or equal to the pivot value, "swap list entries to move that value to the lower end of the table." If you do the coding right, this will not be needed and you can just leave the value in place. If the value is greater than the pivot value, swap list entries to move the examined value to the upper end of the table. You stop when you have examined all the list entries. If you really need the pivot value between the two sublists, make one last swap to put the pivot value in its proper place.

You need two variables to keep track of the limits of the examined lower part of the list and the examined upper part of the list. The unexamined values will be between these two sublists. These variables are indices into the list--much of your code will deal with using and updating these indices as you progress through the table's values.

Now think about the exact definition of those two key index variables, their initial values, how they change for each examined value, and just when you will stop the loop that examines the list's values.

Note that the algorithm I suggest is not the best way to do the partition. There is another, more complex algorithm that reduces the number of swaps. But you should learn to crawl before you walk, and my suggestion does get the job done with the same order of execution time.

Comment: Well, I thought about it, my problem as stated in my last comment up there to Aurora0001, is that I don't know how to start typing the code, even though I have that understanding as you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: @Shalom.I: If you understand what I wrote, then briefly give your definitions and names of the two key index variables, their initial values, and the condition that shows the partition is done. You need to show some work of your own: I won't do your homework for you. If you show real effort then I can lead you a little further. What I ask for here does not require Python code, just showing real understanding that you will later use for actual code.